# Is it possible to make user add a different filter to my filter from the filter gallery

Tags: instagram, spark-ar-studio

I will create an Instagram filter on Spark Ar studio. This filter does not change anything on your face but gives some functionality. I want the user can select another filter (When he or she is using my filter) from the filter gallery and be able to use both my and selected filter. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you wanna use exactly two filters at the same time but you can use one effect and apply the second one on top of the first recorded video.

There is no functionality in spark ar to have two effects active since you can only select one at a time. If you can describe the wish scenario better you can send a feature request to spark ar inside the program's reporting tool.

Alternatively if you build a reels video you can apply effects to different videos in the reel.